# How to shift Camera view over the display boundry?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, virtual-reality

I'm using Unity 2020.1.17f1, for making a simple demo for VR.

Because of mis-align issue of display and optical components(Lens), I want to shift left and right camera view in dynamically and respectively with out changing shape.

So, I tried it by changing x and y value of viewport rect, but it won't work properly when I try to shift image over display.

for example, if I try to shift left camera view to left side, it is squeezed in horizontal direction. As same, If it try to shift camera view in vertical direction, it is squeezed in vertical direction.

I expected part that placed on out of display would be cropped, and last would be shown.

Consider display size is 100*50, and size of each camera view is 50 * 50. Left camera view would be drawn from 0, 0 to 50,50 and right camera view would be drawn from 50,0 to 100,50.
I want to shift left camera view 10 pixels in left direction. Then, left camera view would be drawn from 0, 0 to 40, 50 by losing 10 * 50 pixels on leftside. So, changed x value of viewport rect to -0.2.
But, left side of left camera view do not over display. And left camera view is squeezed 1o pixels making gap between left and right camera view.

It was very long introduction.

Question is simple.

How can I shift camera view over display without changing its shape?

PS. May I have to use Surface shader with offset?

PPS. I think my code won't help you to give me a salvation, but here's part of my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{    

    public Camera LCam;    
    public Camera RCam;    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {

        LCam = transform.Find("Camera_L").GetComponent<Camera>();
        RCam = transform.Find("Camera_R").GetComponent<Camera>();        

    }

    //variables that counting how much camera view has shifted.
    float L_x_Shift, L_y_Shift, R_x_Shift, R_y_Shift = 0;

    //x, y variables of each camera's viewport.
    public float L_ViewPortx = 0;
    public float L_ViewPorty = 0;
    public float R_ViewPortx = 0.5f;
    public float R_ViewPorty = 0;

    void Update()
    {
       
        // each of u,h,j,k shift left camera view in upward, left, downward, right. 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
        {
            L_y_Shift += 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
        {
            L_y_Shift -= 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            L_x_Shift -= 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
        {
            L_x_Shift += 1;
        }
        else { }

        // each numpad 8,4,5,6 shift right camera view in upward, left, downward, right.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad8))
        {
            R_y_Shift += 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad5))
        {
            R_y_Shift -= 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad4))
        {
            R_x_Shift -= 1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad6))
        {
            R_x_Shift += 1;
        }
        else { }

        // reset left camera view
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            L_x_Shift = 0;
            L_y_Shift = 0;
        }
        // reset right camera view.
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            R_x_Shift = 0.5f;
            R_y_Shift = 0;
        }
        else { }
        // Display resolution is 1920 * 2160
        L_ViewPortx = L_x_Shift / 1920;
        L_ViewPorty = L_y_Shift / 2160;
        R_ViewPortx = 0.5f + R_x_Shift / 1920;
        R_ViewPorty = R_y_Shift / 2160;
                
        LCam.rect = new Rect(L_ViewPortx, L_ViewPorty, 0.5f, 1);
        RCam.rect = new Rect(R_ViewPortx, R_ViewPorty, 0.5f, 1);


    }

     
}
```

Comment: What about instead of shift the Rect rather rotate the camera slightly about e.g. 5° ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @derHugo. But rotating camera would not helpful because what i want is moving where camera view shown on display, not moving where camera view showing. 
Easily, what I want is when camera view is drawn from 10,10 to 100,100 on display, let it be drawn from 20, 10 to 110, 100 on display by shifting camera view 10 pixels in right direction.

Comment: so just to understand correctly, you do not want to shift the content this camera is rendering but what you want is shift where on the screen the rendered output is drawn?

Comment: Yes It is. Sorry for my poor english and poor expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an oblique camera frustum, aka modifying the camera projection matrix. Luckily there's an easy way to do it in Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ObliqueFrustum.html

> **Setting Frustum Obliqueness with a Lens Shift**
> Enable a camera’s Physical Camera properties to expose the Lens Shift options. You can use these to offset the camera’s focal center along the X and Y axes in a way that minimizes distortion of the rendered image.
> Shifting the lens reduces the frustum angle on the side opposite the direction of the shift. For example, as you shift the lens up, the angle between the bottom of the frustum and the camera’s center line gets smaller.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hoped it work and help me, but it didn't. I think it might because I applied shader on camera. I guess you recommended it because I mentioned lens-display mis-align. It would very helpful if I applied my shader on some an additional filter before normal camera(then I can shift the filter, not camera view screen.).